# White space on right side of mobile site

Tags: html, css

When I view my website on a mobile screen of iphone there is a white space on the right side of the screen and I can't figure out what is causing it. It seems to be only in the header section too.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

[URL](http://searchtransparency.net/davidhecht/)

Answer (score 1):

I see your site and i think that your site is work fine in browser but it create a problem with mobile your site is fully responsive and there not any white space in desktop resize but your media query not work in mobile so put this meta tag in your head tag and check again in mobile

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
margin:o;
```

if you post your code, i can provide you the accurate answer and one more thing not every one have IPhone lol :)